# Error 'Input string was not in a correct format' in Label Text

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need to convert one label string to int and another one to float, so I can get the total price with the amount and the unit price.

Here's what I tried:

```
  private void EntQtde_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        /**/
        if(entRSVenda.Text != null)
        {
            float RSVenda = float.Parse(entRSVenda.Text);
            int Qtde = int.Parse(entQtde.Text);
            lblValorTot.Text = (Qtde * RSVenda).ToString();
            //lblValorTot.Text = ((float.Parse(entRSVenda.Text)) * int.Parse(entQtde.Text)).ToString();
        }

    }



  private void EntRSVenda_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        /**/

        if (entQtde.Text != null)
        {
            float RSVenda = float.Parse(entRSVenda.Text);
            int Qtde = int.Parse(entQtde.Text); 
            //lblValorTot.Text = ((float.Parse(entRSVenda.Text)) * int.Parse(entQtde.Text)).ToString();
            lblValorTot.Text = (Qtde * RSVenda).ToString();


        }

    }
```

When one label text changes, it should make the math again, but everything I tried won't work.

Edit:
The labels don't have any text, it gets the user input

```
<Label Text="" x:Name="lblValorTot"/>


<Entry x:Name="entQtde" Placeholder="Quantidade" Keyboard="Numeric" TextChanged="EntQtde_TextChanged"/>

<Entry x:Name="entRSVenda" Placeholder="Valor unitário (R$)" TextChanged="EntRSVenda_TextChanged" />
```

Could it be the placeholder 'R$'?

Comment: And do you believe the input should parse?  Try using the TryParse() method instead of parse.

Comment: Show the out put.This parse is surely working.

Comment: Can you show us the _exact_ content of the two labels? Something is not parsable to float and/or integer. Perhaps you have the currency symbol in those fields. As @GinjaNinja has already told you, use the TryParse method from float and int to check if the value can be parsed

Comment: It won't let me use TryParse, I don't know why, it appears "no overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: @Newton Then you aren't using it correctly and you need to show us how you're trying to use it.

Comment: I think I really don't know how to use it. It isn't just 'float.TryParse(entRSVenda.Text)'?

Comment: @Newton when you don't know how to use a library method you should try to search for its documentation. There is a lot of information available for your knowledge just [typing some text in a search engine](https://www.bing.com/search?q=decimal.TryParse&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=decimal.tryparse&sc=7-16&sk=&cvid=7C8928C784F84251B4FA295A0A9C6C97)

Comment: `float RSVenda; float.TryParse(entRSVenda.Text, out RSVenda);` What's the value of `entRSVenda.Text` at runtime when you debug?

Comment: You're not giving us much to go on.  I've put some code in answer below to get you moving in right direction.  Also consider that you are checking one textbox has an input (you should also check for empty string) and then assuming that the other does.

Comment: Storing data in the UI - that is using controls as variables - is a very bad practice.  Use actual classes and variables and simply use the GUI as a *view* of the data for the user.  You'll be glad you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've not seen any input example yet, but hopefully snippet below will get you up and running:

```
    if (entQtde.Text != null)
    {
        int Qtde;
        bool canParse = int.TryParse(entQtde.Text, out Qtde); 

        if(canParse){
           lblValorTot.Text = (Qtde * RSVenda).ToString();
        }else{
           // invalid input - do something!
        }


    }
```